# Using CFEXECUTE to generate SVN log problems

Tags: svn, coldfusion, bluedragon, cfexecute

I'm trying to use a CFEXECUTE command to generate an SVN log file for me.  The problem I'm running into is the log file is coming back empty.  I'm using SlikSVN and BlueDragon 7.1.0 on a Windows 7 machine:

```
<cftry>
   <cfset svnDir = "http://SVNSERVER" />
   <cfset svnExe = "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe" />
   <cfset svnArg = 'log --xml -v #svnDir#' />

   <cfexecute name="#svnExe#" arguments="#svnArg#" timeout="10" variable="changes">  
   </cfexecute>
   <cfdump var="#changes#">

   <cfcatch><cfdump var="#cfcatch#"></cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

The result I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <log>
```

I'm running the BlueDragon service under my credentials.  I've also tried adding in my SVN credentials to the arguments and it still generates an empty log.  I've also tried checking out the SVN repository to a local folder and using that as a path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been fighting this for a while now.  :)

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you run `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe log --xml -v http://SVNSERVER` from the command line on the ColdFusion server?

Comment: @Miguel If I check the code out to a local folder, I can run this command from a bat file in that folder:  `svn log --xml -v -r {2010-01-01}:{2014-01-31} > svn.log`.  Being able to do something similar on a scheduled task with CFEXECUTE is the goal. :)

Comment: I understand. My point is that you need to get the command working from the command line first, then migrate that syntax into your `cfexecute` syntax. Looking at the two examples that you have given; they are different.

Comment: @Miguel Sorry for the confusion, I have a lot of iterations of this command about as I've been trying things to make it work.  `svn log --xml -v "http://SVNSERVER" > svn.log` works from the command line, but not from the CFEXECUTE statement I listed above.  The only difference is I'm piping it to a file in the command line and I'm trying to dump the results in the CFEXECUTE right now while I trouble shoot.

Comment: Yeah the piping to a file is irrelevant. Just to be clear, you are not getting any errors running the command via `cfexecute`. Right? However running the command from ColdFusion is not providing the same output as when running from the command line?

Comment: @Miguel No error, just empty XML that starts off with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <log>`.  I've tried adding in my SVN credentials, but I just get the same thing.

Comment: Are you running in a timeout? I just tried this and I get the same lines, some seconds nothing and then the <logentry revision="297"> entity. Try to increase the timeout. When you try the command line, are you the same user as your coldfusion service?